# How make that my left click of the mouse draw a cercle in the board tic tac toe game with tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

This is my code where players choose the position of the cercle. Now the objective is that my left click of the mouse indicate the positions of the cercles. I have an idea with def motion but i don't know how to look forward with it. Any idea

'''code'''

```
import tkinter              
root=tkinter.Tk(
#let's create background

finestra = tkinter.Canvas(root,
borderwidth = 0, 
background = 'blue',
cursor = 'circle', 
height=600, 
width=600)
def ini_finestra(finestra):
    finestra
    finestra.pack()
ini_finestra(finestra)

alturay=0
dx=0

def ini_graella(): #draw the board
# create horizontal line

    finestra.create_line(75,75+alturay ,
                    525, 75+alturay,                   
                    fill = 'red',
                    width = '5')
# draw vertical line
    finestra.create_line(75+dx,75 ,
                    75+dx,525 ,                   
                    fill = 'red',
                    width = '5')
linia=4     
while linia>0:
    ini_graella()
    linia=linia-1
    alturay=alturay+150
    dx=dx+150
    
    AX=0
    AY=0
    def marca_casella1():
        finestra.create_oval(75+75,75+75,
                       225,225+AX,
                       fill='green',
                        width='0')

    
def player_1():
    finestra.create_oval(75+150*(torn_player_1_fila-1),75+150*(torn_player_1_columna-1),
                        (150+75)+150*(torn_player_1_fila-1),(225)+150*(torn_player_1_columna-1),
                        fill="green",
                        width=3)
def player_2():   
    finestra.create_oval(75+150*(torn_player_2_fila-1),75+150*(torn_player_2_columna-1),
                        (150+75)+ 150*(torn_player_2_fila-1),(150+75)+150*(torn_player_2_columna-1),
                        fill="grey",
                         width=3)
posicion=2
while posicion>0:
    torn_player_1_fila=int(input("Player 1 elige la fila de tu ficha"))
    torn_player_1_columna=int(input("Player 1 elige la columna tu ficha"))
    torn_player_2_fila=int(input("Player 2 elige la fila de tu ficha"))
    torn_player_2_columna=int(input("Player 2 elige la columna de tu ficha"))
    player_1()
    player_2()
    posicion=posicion-2
    

finestra.mainloop()
```

Do you have any idea what i suposed to do?

Comment: I'd like to help but your formatting is broken and we'd have to guess where indentation should be. Please edit and ensure proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

```py
def draw_circle_in_box(x, y):
    offset_x, offset_y = 75, 75
    box_size = 150

    box_x_id = (x - offset_x) // box_size
    box_y_id = (y - offset_y) // box_size

    if box_x_id > 2 or box_x_id < 0 or box_y_id > 2 or box_y_id < 0:
        return # Out of bounds

    finestra.create_oval(box_x_id * box_size + offset_x,
                         box_y_id * box_size + offset_y,
                         box_x_id * box_size + offset_x + box_size,
                         box_y_id * box_size + offset_y + box_size,
                         fill="grey",
                         width=3)


def click_callback(event):
    draw_circle_in_box(event.x, event.y)


finestra.bind("<Button-1>", click_callback)
```

As for the circle having the right color, and you registering it having been entererd by the right player, you should turn `click_callback()` into a method that will be part of a game class, where it will be able to access the current player as you'll store it as an attribute. There are no other simple ways for you to know what color to give it, other than global variables (which are considered bad practice for many reasons).

I haven't implemented it for you because it implies refactoring your code a lot, and I won't write what seems to be a school project for you. If you can't get your new code working, please open another thread.

Comment: okey thanks to your comment, it give me  an idea how i should look forward.

Comment: @LOS4A Sure thing. Remember to close the thread